# React PWA : How to properly setup the manifest file and register service worker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I am new to react and was learning react by developing a small application. The app was bootstrapped using create-react-app and was deployed using github pages. Everything works fine but i cannot get the PWA part of the app working.

If i click add to home screen option from Application tab in the chrome Dev tool, I'm getting the following error

> Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may
>   need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the
>   current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

My manifest.json file looks like this

```
{
  "short_name": "Bill Splitter",
  "name": "205 Bill Splitter",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "192X192 144X144 64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I don't have much knowledge about the service workers and my belief was that it will get registered automatically to the app. But i am  not sure whether the build  process is doing this. How can i do this.

A live version of the app can be found in this link 
https://jishnuramesh.github.io/bill-splitter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the facebook docs,

> By default, the build process will generate a service worker file, but
>   it will not be registered, so it will not take control of your
>   production web app.

In order to opt-in to the offline-first behavior, developers should look for the following in their src/index.js file:

```
// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

As the comment states, switching serviceWorker.unregister() to serviceWorker.register() will opt you in to using the service worker.

refer : https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app

Comment: Thanks Dhananjai , I went through the entire docs yesterday and  completed missed it. TBH i didnt know much about service worker either. If you have any resources please feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "short_name": "React PWA App",
  "name": "ReactJS PWA App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Here is a simple **svcWorker.js**

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'task-manager-pwa';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/completed'
];

// Install service worker
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  // Perform the install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Cache opened');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

// Cache and return the requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Return response as Cache is hit 
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});

// Update service worker
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  var cacheWhitelist = ['task-manager-pwa'];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

To use service worker use this code in **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.register();
```

I have explained the steps to create a simple React PWA App with working code in GitHub in a blog post. Please refer to: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2019/10/react-pwa-tutorial.html